# Long blade comments prevent server response

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

So I've been having this issue where longer comments in my Blade templates will cause the WAMP instance I have running on my local machine to respond with "This webpage is not available" when I try to access the page in Chrome.

The template I am responding with form my controller via View::make() is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    {{--
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam, facilis, provident, natus praesentium sed nihil perferendis saepe hic consequuntur tempora omnis consectetur aliquid accusamus. Laudantium, a, pariatur in officia ut dicta doloribus distinctio maiores magni iusto minima quibusdam dignissimos nemo culpa aut dolor enim blanditiis porro facere ex consequatur facilis voluptatibus rem error quidem nam quo quis ad soluta beatae voluptate quisquam commodi maxime! Ullam, veritatis, enim dicta at vero quidem accusamus. Labore, tempore, esse sint suscipit tempora temporibus quam libero eligendi cum quas corrupti ducimus adipisci recusandae debitis fugit illo numquam saepe ullam sit tenetur odit voluptates perspiciatis nulla quo placeat aperiam nisi animi hic rerum ratione. Suscipit, ipsam, explicabo, dolores consectetur quas aliquam animi deserunt iusto commodi eaque voluptate aperiam non atque totam corporis quam tempore at accusamus! Molestiae, repellat beatae adipisci eaque doloribus earum voluptate voluptatum saepe sequi tempora similique quidem debitis quas nam eligendi et ex architecto porro consequuntur itaque explicabo tenetur nulla quam quaerat sed cum aliquid quisquam recusandae laudantium minus numquam eius dolore odio iusto optio soluta minima facere voluptatibus autem vel ut est totam neque dicta quis voluptatem! Deserunt, vero, odit pariatur maxime quisquam delectus fuga enim quis sapiente accusantium asperiores alias voluptas ullam facilis praesentium beatae nisi iure numquam? Voluptatibus, repellat doloremque quia aliquid amet ea nostrum reiciendis ipsum non unde ullam repudiandae omnis. Cupiditate, at ullam eius possimus necessitatibus commodi repudiandae excepturi exercitationem sint ipsum dolorem totam a porro quaerat odit fugiat nisi? Quo, assumenda, sit eos sint magnam laudantium veniam officia delectus minima ipsa corrupti ut impedit dolore minus et id dignissimos quam quod reprehenderit est obcaecati expedita quos hic quis odio nulla nobis itaque facilis cum ducimus numquam suscipit eligendi praesentium ea aliquid ullam doloremque ad repellendus ex optio vero tempora error neque alias consectetur dolorum. Cumque, officiis, aliquam!
    --}}    

</body>
</html>
```

When I shorten or remove the comment, the server responds just fine. What could be causing this? I won't *need* comments in my production code, but I like to keep things commented while working, and I like being able to comment out sections of code where HTML comments would be inconvenient.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, there is not extra routing or controller logic going on. Just

```
// routes.php
Route::get('/', 'StaticController@showIndex');


// StaticController.php
public function showIndex() {
    return View::make('static.index');
}
```

**EDIT:** With some experimentation, I have determined that the maximum comment length before the error occurs is 631 characters inside the {{-- --}} delimiters. Adding one additional character causes the error.

Comment: Does the filename for this view ends with `.blade.php`?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this error. I've just copied this code to a fresh laravel installation and everything works fine.

Comment: The filename does end with `.blade.php`